# Oracle: Nested joins/sub-queries: Odd column names and one unexplained error

Tags: sql, oracle, join, nested, subquery

The following query works fine. It is a series of nested joins to give me a kind of master table:

```
SELECT *
FROM proj_trainer k 
JOIN
(
SELECT * 
    FROM proj_breeder i
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM proj_jockey g
        JOIN
        (
        SELECT *
            FROM proj_horses e 
            JOIN
            (
            SELECT *
                FROM proj_results c
                JOIN
                    (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM proj_race_details a
                    JOIN proj_meet b
                    ON a.meet_id = b.meet_id
                    ) d
                ON c.race_id = d.race_id
            ) f 
            ON e.horse_id = f.horse_id
        ) h 
        ON g.jockey_id = h.jockey_id
    )j 
    ON i.breeder_id = j.breeder_id
) l 
ON k.trainer_id = l.trainer_id;
```

This works fine with one odd feature, which isn't my main problem. Some of the columns are return with strange codes such as "QCSJ_C000000001300001". Not sure why, or if this relates to my actual problem.

The real problem is that when I add just one more join sub-query I get:

```
ORA-00904: "N"."RACE_ID": invalid identifier
```

Here's the same code with the extra nested block (the one on the very outside)

```
SELECT *
FROM proj_entry m   
JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM proj_trainer k 
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM proj_breeder i
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM proj_jockey g
            JOIN
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM proj_horses e 
                JOIN
                (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM proj_results c
                    JOIN
                        (
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM proj_race_details a
                        JOIN proj_meet b
                        ON a.meet_id = b.meet_id
                        ) d
                    ON c.race_id = d.race_id
                ) f 
                ON e.horse_id = f.horse_id
            ) h 
            ON g.jockey_id = h.jockey_id
        )j 
        ON i.breeder_id = j.breeder_id
    ) l 
    ON k.trainer_id = l.trainer_id
) n
ON n.race_id = m.race_id WHERE n.horse_id = m.horse_id;
```

I felt like I was well over the hill with this one and then the final line went wrong somehow, despite having virtually the same structure as all the previous blocks. I've also used the race_id and horse_id earlier in the code so they do work.

I've also tried this on the last line:

```
ON n.race_id = m.race_id AND n.horse_id = m.horse_id;
```

and a few other variations, with brackets etc....

Comment: See **DocId 2658003.1** `"QCSJ_C"` is used internally when Oracle transforms ANSI style joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I could't see anything wrong as such, but then I can't see anything terribly well with that syntax!  The problem may be that `"N"."RACE_ID"` is ambiguous, since `"N"` is the alias for a query that joins many tables, perhaps more than one of which have a `RACE_ID` column?

Your SQL could be re-written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM proj_entry m   
JOIN proj_trainer n ON n.race_id = m.race_id
JOIN proj_breeder l ON l.trainer_id = n.trainer_id
JOIN proj_jockey j ON j.breeder_id = l.breeder_id
JOIN proj_horses h ON h.jockey_id = j.jockey_id
JOIN proj_results f ON f.horse_id = h.horse_id
JOIN proj_race_details d ON d.race_id = f.race_id
JOIN proj_meet b ON b.meet_id = d.meet_id
WHERE n.horse_id = m.horse_id;
```

(But I could have made a mistake somewhere.)

That looks a lot simpler to me.  It would be better still if the aliases were mnemonics for the actual table names rather than in most cases arbitrary letters of the alphabet:

```
SELECT *
FROM proj_entry e   
JOIN proj_trainer t ON t.race_id = e.race_id
JOIN proj_breeder b ON b.trainer_id = n.trainer_id
JOIN proj_jockey j ON j.breeder_id = b.breeder_id
JOIN proj_horses h ON h.jockey_id = j.jockey_id
JOIN proj_results r ON r.horse_id = h.horse_id
JOIN proj_race_details d ON d.race_id = r.race_id
JOIN proj_meet m ON m.meet_id = d.meet_id
WHERE t.horse_id = e.horse_id;
```

You should then easily be able to check the joins to see that they are on the right columns.  And now if you get an error like `ORA-00904: "T"."RACE_ID": invalid identifier` you will know for sure that it refers to table `proj_trainer` whereas previously `"N"."RACE_ID"` might be ambiguous since "N" was the alias of a query joining about half a dozen tables.

Also rather than `SELECT *` it might be better to specify the actual columns you want, which will avoid getting duplicates - for example:

```
SELECT e.race_id, t.trainer_id, t.trainer_name, ...
```

(I imagine the column names starting with 'QCSJ' that your query tool is generating are to cope with what would otherwise be duplicate column names in the results. What is the query tool?)

Comment: Thanks Tony. Your method worked and I didn't get any strange column names either. I only nested them because I thought it was necessary, actually. Certainly easier to read/implement.

Comment: Do you know how I might select owners at the top of the block and return just one owner (any owner) when their are multiple owners? I was thinking of using MIN(i.owner_id) as a select and at the very end appending to the block: GROUP BY (i.owner_id). That was my best effort, but it's pretty lame.

Comment: You can do this: `SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM ...`